# What's the easiest way to share the files from a computer with another computer via local network?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, nautilus

My case is that I have a computer running Ubuntu Server and optionally OpenBox (for UI). When I start it and want to work on it I have to login (in the tty1) and then `startx`.

I would like to access this computer files from another computer (e.g. my laptop).

```
        Wifi Router -------------
      /                          \
     |                            \
     Wifi Connection               Eth
     |                              |
     |                              |
 ---------                        -------------
 My laptop                        Ubuntu Server
 ---------                        -------------
```

Currently I can access my Ubuntu Server machine via `ssh`, and that's cool:

```
ssh -A ionicabizau@192.168.2.112
```

But, the ip is changing after restarting the machine. Instead of `112` it can be `107`, for instance.

I can do pretty much the same thing in nautilus and browse the files on the computer, which is again cool.

But how can I make Nautilus to detect the ip which could be changed after one day?

How can I detect that in the terminal as well?

Is there a better way to do it? Until now the easiest way is via ssh since I can use my ssh keys as well for authentication.

Comment: Take a look at [NitroShare](https://nitroshare.net/).

Comment: @Mitch Thanks, I just did. I'd actually want to use Nautilus for browsing the files and `ssh` to run commands on that computer.

Comment: Go to your router's settings and bind your server's MAC address to an IP address…